# Neo4j FAST API add labels dynamically

Tags: python, neo4j, fastapi

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
 from pydantic import BaseModel
 import os
 from dotenv import load_dotenv
 from neo4j import GraphDatabase

 load_dotenv()
 uri=os.getenv("uri")
 user=os.getenv("user")
 pwd=os.getenv("pwd")

 class nodemodel(BaseModel):
    label:str
    name:str

 def connection():
    driver=GraphDatabase.driver(uri=uri,auth=(user,pwd))
    return driver

 app=FastAPI()

 @app.post("/createNode")
 def createnode(node:nodemodel):
    driver_neo4j=connection()
    session=driver_neo4j.session()
    q1="""
    CREATE(n{name:$name}) WITH n
    CALL apoc.create.addLabels(n, [$label]) YIELD node
    return n.name as name
    """
    x={"name":node.name, "label":node.label}
    results=session.run(q1,x)
    return {"response" +results}
```

Thats my current code for a Neo4j REST API and it is working but i want to add labels more dynamically instead of just one. I want to type into the Request Body of my API:

```
{
  "labels": "Label1:Label2:Label3",
  "name": "string"
 }
or just
 {
  "labels": "Label1",
  "name": "string"
 }
```

and i want both Options to work. Is there a way to do this, can someone show me an example with code?

Kind Regards
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix some of the syntax errors on your script. See below:

1. The APOC apoc.create.addLabels parameters are both list so make (nodes, $labels) as lists.  Pass nodes as collect(n) and labels as ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3"]
2. In the query, during CREATE  you need to use a node class name so I used SampleNode
3. In your query, use node.name rather than n.name

Sample value of x:

x= {"labels": ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3"], "name": "Sample Name"}

```
q1="""
CREATE (n:SampleNode {name:$name}) 
WITH collect(n) as nodes
CALL apoc.create.addLabels(nodes, $labels) YIELD node
return node.name as name"""
"""
x={"name":node.name, "labels":node.labels}
results=session.run(q1,x)
```

I tested it in my python notebook and it looks like this:
[image]